# pdm-installed streamlit fails to launch a server

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, streamlit, python-pdm

I have installed `streamlit` on my Mac with [`pdm`](https://pdm.fming.dev) and launched the command `streamlit hello` to view the demos. The command returns the following:

```
❯ pdm run streamlit hello
2022-03-21 11:43:45.812 WARNING streamlit.config:
Warning: the config option 'server.enableCORS=false' is not compatible with 'server.enableXsrfProtection=true'.
As a result, 'server.enableCORS' is being overridden to 'true'.

More information:
In order to protect against CSRF attacks, we send a cookie with each request.
To do so, we must specify allowable origins, which places a restriction on
cross-origin resource sharing.

If cross origin resource sharing is required, please disable server.enableXsrfProtection.

2022-03-21 11:43:45.816 DEBUG   streamlit.logger: Initialized tornado logs
2022-03-21 11:43:45.818 DEBUG   matplotlib.pyplot: Loaded backend agg version unknown.
2022-03-21 11:43:45.819 DEBUG   streamlit.bootstrap: Setting up signal handler
2022-03-21 11:43:45.819 DEBUG   asyncio: Using selector: KqueueSelector
2022-03-21 11:43:45.827 DEBUG   streamlit.server.server: Starting server...
2022-03-21 11:43:45.827 DEBUG   streamlit.server.server: Serving static content from the Node dev server
2022-03-21 11:43:45.830 DEBUG   streamlit.server.server: Server started on port 8501
2022-03-21 11:43:45.831 DEBUG   streamlit.server.server: Server state: State.INITIAL -> State.WAITING_FOR_FIRST_BROWSER
2022-03-21 11:43:46.029 DEBUG   git.cmd: Popen(['git', 'version'], cwd=<my/working/directory>, universal_newlines=False, shell=None, istream=None)
2022-03-21 11:43:46.041 DEBUG   git.cmd: Popen(['git', 'version'], cwd=<my/working/directory>, universal_newlines=False, shell=None, istream=None)
2022-03-21 11:43:46.054 DEBUG   git.cmd: Popen(['git', 'version'], cwd=<my/working/directory>, universal_newlines=False, shell=None, istream=None)
2022-03-21 11:43:46.066 DEBUG   git.cmd: Popen(['git', 'rev-parse', '--show-toplevel'], cwd=<my/working/directory>, universal_newlines=False, shell=None, istream=None)

  Welcome to Streamlit. Check out our demo in your browser.

  Local URL: http://localhost:3000
  Network URL: http://192.168.1.117:3000

  Ready to create your own Python apps super quickly?
  Head over to https://docs.streamlit.io

  May you create awesome apps!
```

However, when I connect to the local URL, the connection is rejected:

[image: Safari Error Message: Rejected Connection]

I tried switching to Brave Browser and Firefox, but I got the same error.

From other SO questions, I tried the following:

```
❯ apachectl configtest
AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for Lucas-MacBook-Air.local
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

I also ran this:

```
ps -ax | grep 'httpd'
  124 ??         0:00.85 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  517 ??         0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 6627 ttys002    0:00.01 grep httpd
```

I tried launching other stuff that creates a local server, e.g. Jupyter Notebooks, and they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is known: `streamlit` [does not support `pdm`](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/3132) at the time of writing, [as mentioned by @cye18 on the parallel issue opened on pdm's github page](https://github.com/pdm-project/pdm/issues/989).

The problem is that, while `streamlit` configs default to server port `8501`, the server is launched on the port `3000`. You can force this behaviour in two ways.

The first is by manually [changing streamlit's settings](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/configuration#set-configuration-options), which lies in [`~/.streamlit/config.toml` or locally in your project directory](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/using-streamlit/path-streamlit-config-toml).

```
[server]
serverPort = 8501
```

Alternatively, you can add the following flag to the `streamlit` command when launching it:

`pdm run streamlit run app.py --server.port 8501`

Either way, `streamlit` will complain by saying that `server.port does not work when global.developmentMode is true`. Once again, this can be solved by adding the flag `--global.developmentMode false`. The final command will look like this: `pdm run streamlit run app.py --server.port 8501 --global.developmentMode false.`

Alternatively, the local settings will look like the following:

```
[server]
port = 8501

[global]
developmentMode = false
```